# How to enable auto-completion with Git [all platforms]

Tags: bash, git, autocomplete

How to enable auto-completion with Git?

When using Git on different platforms, auto-completion is not always enabled/available.

Note that this question is NOT a duplicate of [git auto-complete for *branches* on the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55875), because that question was only about Apple users. This question is mostly the same, but including other platforms too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get `bash`'s programmable completion configured to return the possible commands. You can see the "Programmable Completion" section in the `bash` man page if you want to implement it yourself.

A much easier method to use a script to pre-configure bash's programmable completion. On most distributions, the file for git completion, `/etc/bash_completion.d/git` (on Fedora and derivatives), `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git` (on Debian and derivatives) (other distributions might have it in other places, try [`locate`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/362341/28015) or [`find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492782/28015) to locate it) are provided by the `git` package. (If it is not included with your git package, you can get it from [here](https://github.com/git/git/raw/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)).

You can configure `bash` to source the file when it is started (probably using `.bashrc`), or you can install [`bash-completion`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion), which will automatically load completions like the one that the `git` package installs (and generally completions from `/etc/bash_completion.d/` or `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/` (typically BSDs)). On most distributions, `bash-completion` should be available in the repositories and you can simply install the package. For other systems, see the instructions included in the `README.md` to install it. (On non-GNU/Linux systems, some completions might need to be disabled to prevent it from outputting errors when starting)

Comment: In Debian 11 (WSL), I found the git script completion on `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git`.

Answer (score 2):

## Apple users

See question [git auto-complete in the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55875)

## Linux users

Solution tested with Debian 9 (Stretch)

```
sudo apt install bash-completion
```

Pros:

- Very easy for newcomers to Linux/scripts
- No "manual" downloading
- Only makes use of the official repos: the "safest" way.
- Easy to update: `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade`

I also know that the question was asked for Apple users, but it shows up first in Google for "git auto-completion branch", so I thought a Linux answer would still be useful.

Comment: this solution is for debian and the package is installed per default. so, useless to install

Comment: Actually it wasn't installed by default on my machine, which is why I created the question

Comment: ok, juste an information. a wrong uninstall? or in debian install withour tasksel?

Comment: The `bash-completion` package does not actually include command completion for `git`, the `git` package does. What `bash-completion` does is set up the shell to automatically load the completions bundled with it and other packages. You can get the completion working without any external files or the `bash-completion` package by adding `source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git` to your .bashrc (Debian / Ubuntu specific)

Comment: Thanks!
I just started using WSL Debian and this was the correct answer for me.  Simple installing bash-completion like this turned on all the already installed completion files.